# Run another command if first command fails on keypress

Tags: key-bindings, external-command

Is it possible to combine the two commands

```
map <F5> :w<CR>:exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
map <F6> :w<CR>:exec '!poetry run'<CR>
```

so that when I press F5, it first tries to run "poetry run" and if that fails, than the file is ran with python directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the shell's `||` operator here:

```
map <F5> :w<CR>:exe printf('!poetry run %s || python %s', shellescape(@%), shellescape(@%))<CR>
```

The way this works in the shell is that the `||` or "or" operator only runs what is on the right-hand side if whatever is on the left-hand side returns with an exit code of 0 (indicating success). It's the same as in `||` and `&&`  in most programming languages:

```
if False || never_actually_tested:
```

If you don't want to do that then you need to use some more complex logic and check `v:shell_error`; I would put that in a function:

```
fun! s:poetry()
  exe '!poetry' shellescape(@%)
  if v:shell_error > 0
      exe '!python' shellescape(@%)
      " Or: call feedkeys("\<F6>") to run whatever "F6" is.
  endif
endfun
map <F5> :w<CR>:call <SID>poetry()<CR>
```

Comment: With `||` short-circuiting bypasses the RHS if the LHS evaluates to true/success. (Since that first line of code is correct this is clearly just a case of a temporary short-circuit in the ol' noggin while writing the description and the `never_actually_tested` example. :)

Comment: Thank you!
I changed the second line to `exe '!poetry run'`, than it works. But the problem is, when `poetry run` fails, then I have to
Press ENTER or type command to continue
I tried to overcome this with changing the 4th line to `feedkeys("\<CR>") exe '!python' shellescape(@%)`, but still have to "press ENTER to continue".
Is it possible, to automate this also, so that the 4th line is ran without me having to press ENTER?

Comment: If you don't care about the output of the commands then adding `silent` in front of them should work @fl_: `silent exe '...'`. You can also use `<silent>` in a mapping: `map <silent> <F5> ...`. Use `silent!` with a `!` if you also want to silence error messages.